# cob_bringup unrecognized as a package

Tags: ros, rosdep, care-o-bot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am running electric on ubuntu 10.4.  I installed ros-electric-care-o-bot according to the instructions.  Then, following the Caro-o-bot instructions for simulation, I attempt to "rosdep install cob_bringup".  I get the error below even though the cob_bringup stack is in my electric directory.

```
rosdep install cob_bringup
Warning: could not identify ['cob_bringup'] as a package
Usage: rosdep [options] <command> <args>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11211/cob_bringup-unrecognized-as-a-package/) by [Paul0nc](https://answers.ros.org/users/1067/paul0nc/) on ROS Answers with karma: 271 on 2011-09-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I just downloaded and installed the Care-O-bot stack to test this problem. I was able to get the rosdep to work correctly with the following commands:

```
roscd cob_apps
rosdep install cob_bringup
```

Just a note, the rosdep for this stack only contains one dependency, and it appears that I already had it on my machine. If this turns out to be the case for you, don't panic if you see the "No packages to install" result.

I hope this helps.

---

Originally posted by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) with karma: 11163 on 2011-09-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1